# Checkbuttons crashes app when checked

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I created a list of checkboxes, and I was trying to increase an int value proportionally to the number of the selected ones. Instead, every time I try to check them (through .isChecked()) the app crashes. I've tried to search everywhere for some solutions, but nothing worked. I really can't understand where is the problem.

Here's the code

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.deadlybanana.myfirstapp.DisplayPicture">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/first"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/unicorn" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/frasenome"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkbox1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Are you Beatiful?" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkbox2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Are you Fabolous?" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkbox3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Are you Unique?" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkbox4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Are you a horse?" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkbox5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Do you eat grass?" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="checkbutton"
            android:text="Check if you are a unicorn" />
        </LinearLayout>


    </ScrollView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Java file

```
package com.example.deadlybanana.myfirstapp;
public class DisplayPicture extends AppCompatActivity {

List<Boolean> checkboxes = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
CheckBox press1;
CheckBox press2;
CheckBox press3;
CheckBox press4;
CheckBox press5;
int points = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_picture);
    Intent intent = getIntent();

    String name = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    CheckBox press1 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkbox1);
    CheckBox press2 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkbox2);
    CheckBox press3 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkbox3);
    CheckBox press4 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkbox4);
    CheckBox press5 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkbox5);

    TextView NameString = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.frasenome);
    String phrase = name + ", are you some of these things?";
    NameString.setText(phrase);
}

public void checkbutton(View view){
    if (press1.isChecked()){
        points += 4;
    }
    if (points > 3){
        Toast.makeText(this, "You are a unicorn", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "You are not a unicorn",   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    }
}
```

(right now it is being examined just the first checkbox to simplify the code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: in `onCreate()`

```
press1 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkbox1);
press2 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkbox2);
press3 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkbox3);
press4 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkbox4);
press5 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkbox5);
```

error occurs as `press1.isChecked()` is refers to the global `CheckBox press1;`

which is not yet initialized..

AS you are initializing the checkbox like:

`CheckBox press1 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkbox1);` inside `onCreate()` which only gives it a local instance which is not accessable in your `checkbutton(View view)` function

**Solution**

remove the local initialization just use: `press1 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkbox1);`

Answer (score 0):

Set id for your button lets assume it be **button** and add the following code

```
Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
 btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            checkbutton();
        }
    });
```

Note:remove the view parameter

Implementing Listeners is the best way to handle the events

Answer (score 0):

I never use the method isChecked() because it never works for me. Do you want to increase the points when you select a checkbutton and maybe show the points when you press a button?

Here is the class code:

```
public class ButtonActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
int points=0;
boolean check1=false;
boolean check2=false;
boolean check3=false;
boolean check4=false;
boolean check5=false;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_button);
    findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),points+"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

public void onClick(View view)
{
    switch(view.getId())
    {
        case R.id.checkBox:
            if(check1)
            {
                check1=false;
                points--;
            }
            else
            {
                check1=true;
                points++;
            }
            break;
        case R.id.checkBox2:
            if(check2)
            {
                check2=false;
                points--;
            }
            else
            {
                check2=true;
                points++;
            }
            break;
        case R.id.checkBox3:
            if(check3)
            {
                check3=false;
                points--;
            }
            else
            {
                check3=true;
                points++;
            }
            break;
        case R.id.checkBox4:
            if(check4)
            {
                check4=false;
                points--;
            }
            else
            {
                check4=true;
                points++;
            }
            break;
        case R.id.checkBox5:
            if(check5)
            {
                check5=false;
                points--;
            }
            else
            {
                check5=true;
                points++;
            }
            break;
    }
}
}
```

Here is the layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_button"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.utente.stackoverflow.ButtonActivity">

<CheckBox
    android:text="CheckBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox"
    android:onClick="onClick"/>

<CheckBox
    android:text="CheckBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
    android:onClick="onClick"/>

<CheckBox
    android:text="CheckBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
    android:onClick="onClick"/>

<CheckBox
    android:text="CheckBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox4"
    android:onClick="onClick"/>

<CheckBox
    android:text="CheckBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox5"
    android:onClick="onClick"/>

<Button
    android:text="Points"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button" />
```

I tested it and it works. I hope this helps you.